# NextJS with SWR is showing initialData during validation when using with getServerSideProps

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swr

I'm using NextJS with SWR to fetch data. I feed SWR with initialData returned by `getServerSideProps`.

Pagination works perfectly fine. When I go to page 3, I see page 3 data. When I go to page 5, I first see page 1 again and then page 5 data. This is happening during validation I think. I want to show page 3 data until page 5 is ready. How can I solve this?

#### My fetcher

```
const fetcher = url => axios.get(url).then(res => res.data)
```

#### How I get data with `getServerSideProps`

```
export const getServerSideProps = async() => {
    const pages = await fetcher('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/pages/')

    return { props: { pages } }
}
```

#### Where I call SWR and render the results

```
function Page ({ pageIndex, props }) {
const { data, error } = useSWR(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/pages/?page=${pageIndex}`, fetcher, {dedupingInterval: 15000, initialData: props.pages, revalidateOnFocus: false});
return (
        {data.results.map(page => <p>page</p>)}
    )

}
```

#### How I call Page and Pagination

```
export default function Pages(props) {
...
const [pageIndex, setPageIndex] = useState(1);
<Page pageIndex={pageIndex} props={props}/>
<Pagination pages={props.genes.total_pages} setPageIndex={setPageIndex}/>
...
}
```

Comment: Could you try moving the useSWR hook to the Pages component and pass just the necessary props down to the Page component. I think the useSWR hook is reinitialized every time the pageIndex changes.

Comment: @MohsinAli Thank you for the comment. I moved useSWR to Pages but didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved by using `useRef` as recommended in this [GitHub post](https://github.com/vercel/swr/issues/192#issuecomment-821848756).

### Updated Page function

```
function Page ({ pageIndex, props }) {
const mutableRef = useRef();
const { data, error } = useSWR(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/pages/?page=${pageIndex}`, fetcher, {dedupingInterval: 15000, initialData: mutableRef.current ? mutableRef.current : props.pages, revalidateOnFocus: false});

if (data !== undefined && mutableRef) {
    mutableRef.current = data;
  }

return (
        {data.results.map(page => <p>page</p>)}
    )

}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving your solution ! It just saved me :D